# Multiple xml namespaces deserilize to one class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have few xsd schema for same data. To keep it simple there is example:

```
Class Human
{
    public int Age {set; get;}
    public string Sex {set; get;}
}
```

And for example we can take 2 xsd schema for this data. In first Age is optional in second nothing is optional. Let's call their namespaces "aaa.xxx\human.v1" and second "aaa.xxx\human.v2"

Can I somehow map both of those namespace during XML deserialization using  `System.Xml.XmlTypeAttribute` Class

Comment: How exactly would you expect this to work? In your example, Age would be a.optional, b.not optional or c. file not found :)?

Comment: Age can stay optional. I dont want to write 2 times same class Human. I want to make that "aaa.xxx\human.v1" namespace and "aaa.xxx\human.v2" deserilize in same Human.